# PDFsharp - Change page size and scale content

Tags: scale, pdfsharp

Is it possible to scale a page from e.g. A2 to A1 with PDFsharp?
I can set the size of the page via Size, Width and Height. But how can I scale the content of the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DrawImage()` to draw an existing PDF page on a new PDF page. You can specify the destination rectangle and thus you can scale the page as needed.

Use the `XPdfForm` class to access the existing PDF file.

See the Two Pages on One sample for details:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/TwoPagesOnOne-sample.ashx

Answer (score 7):

based on the comment from Vive and the link provided there, here an example for resizing to A4 with C#:

you must include:

```cs
    using PdfSharp.Pdf;
    using PdfSharp.Drawing;
    using PdfSharp;
```

then:

```cs
    // resize this  file from A3 to A4
    string filename = @"C:\temp\A3.pdf";

    // Create the new output document (A4)
    PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();
    outputDocument.PageLayout = PdfPageLayout.SinglePage;

    XGraphics gfx;
    XRect box;
    // Open the file to resize
    XPdfForm form = XPdfForm.FromFile(filename);

    // Add a new page to the output document
    PdfPage page = outputDocument.AddPage();

    if (form.PixelWidth > form.PixelHeight)
         page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
    else
         page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;

     double width = page.Width;
     double height = page.Height;

     gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
     box = new XRect(0, 0, width, height);
     gfx.DrawImage(form, box);

     // Save the document...
     string newfilename = @"c:\temp\resized.pdf";
     outputDocument.Save(newfilename);
```